# how to pass additional argument along with *args in Python

Tags: python, args

I have a function that takes *arg and an additional positional argument. but when calling this function I am getting below error. Any help how to pass this additional argument

```
**error**:
export_bundle() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'dict'
```

```
from stix2 import MemoryStore, Identity
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')

id1 = Identity(
    name="John Smith",
    identity_class="individual",
    description="Just some guy",
)
id2 = Identity(
    name="John Smith",
    identity_class="individual",
    description="A person",
)

dict= {"id":1234, "name":"abd"}

def export_bundle(self, *args, dict):
   mem = MemoryStore()
   for sdo in args:
      mem.add([sdo])
   mem.save_to_file(self.output_location + str(dict['id']) + timestamp+ '.json')
    del mem

export_bundle(id1, id2, dict)
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully: missing a **keyword-only argument**.

Comment: You can't define a function that takes positional arguments after `*args`.

Answer (score 3):

You declared the function `export_bundle` with variable number of arguments (`*args`), so if you want to define the `dict` argument at the end it needs to be keyword-only parameter (`dict`). You can call it as `export_bundle(id1, id2, dict=dict)` if you want to pass a value for `dict`.

```
def export_bundle(self, *args, dict):
   mem = MemoryStore()
   for sdo in args:
      mem.add([sdo])
   mem.save_to_file(self.output_location + str(dict['id']) + timestamp+ '.json')
   del mem

export_bundle(id1, id2, dict=dict)
```

Comment: Adding `=None` in the function definition does not make the argument keyword-only. Putting it after a `*` argument is what makes it keyword-only. `=None` in the definition gives the argument a default value, which is a completely unrelated thing.

Comment: `thing=whatever` in a function *call* passes an argument by keyword. `thing=whatever` in a function *definition* gives the argument a default value. These two things are 100% unrelated, but happen to use confusingly similar syntax.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You're right. I just tested it and it seems to be the case. I've removed the `=None` for minimizing changes from OP's code

Comment: I am getting below error as well when I called the function as you have suggested: 'dict' object has no attribute 'output_location' . There must be some way to pass self argument

Comment: @st_bones The error you're getting doesn't seem to be related to your previous error. It's because you're accessing the property `output_location` of `self` parameter, in this case `id1`, which doesn't exist in Identity object. https://docs.oasis-open.org/cti/stix/v2.1/cs01/stix-v2.1-cs01.html#_wh296fiwpklp

Answer (score 0):

Always function parameters first & then *args, **kwargs

````
def export_bundle(self, dictm,*args):
   mem = MemoryStore()
   for sdo in args:
      mem.add([sdo])
   mem.save_to_file(self.output_location + str(dict['id']) + timestamp+ '.json')
    del mem```
````

Comment: I am getting below error when I called the function as you have suggested:  `'dict' object has no attribute 'output_location'` . There must be some way to pass self argument?